# How can I validate scopes using API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-api-gateway

I am trying to validate the user's JWT on API Gateway. I can successfully validate JWT itself and its audience. On top of that, I want to block endpoints if a user has not the right scope, e.g., requests to "/api/v1/separate" should not be forwarded to service if the user has not the "separate-stuff" scope.

Here's how my JWT looks like, with the wrong scope:

```
{
  "exp": 1625718360,
  "iat": 1625700360,
  ...
  "scope": "ship-stuff"
}
```

and my API Gateway YML:

```
info:
  title: My Gateway
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/separate:
    get:
      security:
        - identity_token: [separate-stuff]
      summary: Home
      description: some description
      operationId: function_api_v1__get
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful Response
    options:
      security:
        - identity_token: [separate-stuff]
      operationId: function_api_v1__options
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
swagger: '2.0'
x-components: {}
x-google-backend:
  address: https://...
  path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
  jwt_audience: https://...
securityDefinitions:
  identity_token:
    type: "oauth2"
    flow: "implicit"
    authorizationUrl: "https://.../auth"
    scopes:
      separate-stuff: "separates stuff"
    x-google-issuer: "https://..."
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://.../certs"
    x-google-audiences: "..."
```

but API Gateway let the request pass to my service. Any ideas on how to perform scope validation at the API Gateway level? I did not want to perform this at my service. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances ?